# addview LinearLayout order problems

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

this is standard addView in a LinearLayout.

```
            table.addView(child);
```

[image]

but i need to add the view in my layout with this way

[image]

Please it is possible to do it??!

Answer (score 4):

Ascending Order:

```
parentView.addView(child, 0);
```

Descending Order:

```
parentView.addView(child, parentView.getChildCount() - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: [addView(View view, int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int%29)

Basically you use this method with 0 for "position" and it will insert the view at the front.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to add items to a Vertically oriented LinearLayout, starting from the bottom to the top.

You could use a RelativeLayout, also vertically oriented, then place your first item with gravity=bottom, then place your next items above that item (relatively).

Answer (score 0):

To better results and control see [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview?gclid=Cj0KCQjwxtSSBhDYARIsAEn0thRGipT4b35cev23BjWrgz5hvKcD28wc_xPOdGH6cg4LUBq1l4VXOMcaArPbEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds).